# Selenium starts Firefox but I get a time out

Tags: .net, selenium, firefox

When I ran my Selenium tests a year ago they worked.
I have since then updated Selenium and Firefox.

Now when I start a test, it fails already at

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver()
```

with a
...`TargetInvocationException`...`--->`
`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:51672/session timed out after 60 seconds.`

Why? Work around?

Firefox starts but nothing loads. The port number (51672) is new for every run.

( I *guess* downgrading Selenium and FF to their respective older versions, whatever they were, would solve the problem; but that is not a way forward. I also have a vague memory of, earlier, having an old version of Se or FF because it wouldn't work otherwise. )

I have Windows10 x64, Firefox quantum 57.0.4 (64-bit), Selenium v.3.8 and dotnet 4.6.1.

Comment: Don't get stuck at `TargetInvocationException` as it does not serve too much of information. You should try to see the `Inner Exception` to get the root cause ,that will help us to chase down the issue. Possibly it was a `NullPointerException`. Show us your code trial as well.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the geckodriver and firefox browser that you're using are both the latest version?

Comment: @DebanjanB Inner exception is WebDriverException and it times out.

Comment: @LoflinA Latest versions on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Selenium 3.0 you also need to download the geckodriver.exe from the below url as per your system configuration.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Then you can try something like this:

```
//Give the path of the geckodriver.exe    
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64","geckodriver.exe")

//Give the path of the Firefox Browser        
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

You may need to or there's ways to specify the geckodriver as an environment variable as well.

Comment: For reference for others: There was no need to specifiy the driver's name (Geckodriver.exe), only the path (@"C:..."). There was no need to set the `FireoxBinaryPath`.